# Prove that for any integer $t$, $x=m+bt$ and $y=n-at$ is also a solution.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Consider the equation $ax+by=c$, where we are trying to find integer solutions for $x$ and $y$. Suppose that $x=m$ and $y=n$ is a solution.

Prove that for any integer $t$, $x=m+bt$ and $y=n-at$ is also a solution.

I am totally stuck and if anyone could just give a theorem or hint that would push me in the right direction that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply substitute $x=m+bt$ and $y=n-at$ into your initial equation $ax+by=c$, expand the LHS and obtain $c$ on the RHS. It is a straightforward computation.

Comment: Cool, thank you very much. It is at least a coherent argument :)